# How do I pivot several different groups of column values in a row into their own single columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I'm wondering how to go from a row such as:

```
create table t1
(
n1 int,
n2 int,
n3 int,
a1 char, 
a2 char,
a3 char,
b1 char, 
b2 char, 
b3 char
)

insert into t1 values (1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

To a query that will return:

```
n1 n2 n3 As Bs

1, 2, 3, a, x 
1, 2, 3, b, y
1, 2, 3, c, z
```

The groups of columns I want to pivot are static and equal in their column count.

Comment: btw.. This prevents me from having to modify a nasty report project.

Comment: What determines that 'a' matches 'x' but not 'y' or 'z'?  Is that because `a1` must pair with `x1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT n1,n2,n3,a,b
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM t1) p
    UNPIVOT (a FOR ACOL IN (a1,a2,a3))AS u1
    UNPIVOT (b FOR BCOL IN (b1,b2,b3))AS u2
WHERE RIGHT(ACOL,1) =  RIGHT(BCOL,1);
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac041/32)

Comment: If I incorporate two more columns, the query doesn't seem to work right.. I must need to adjust the where clause somehow? `SELECT n1,n2,n3,a AS AValues,b As BValues, c As CValues, d As DValues 
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM t1) p
    UNPIVOT (a FOR ACOL IN (a1,a2,a3))AS u1
    UNPIVOT (b FOR BCOL IN (b1,b2,b3))AS u2
    UNPIVOT (c FOR CCOL IN (c1,c2,c3))AS u3
    UNPIVOT (d FOR DCOL IN (d1,d2,d3))AS u4
WHERE RIGHT(ACOL,1) =  RIGHT(BCOL,1);` [fiddle link..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6978/3)

Comment: @user2027080, you need to add this to where clause `AND RIGHT(ACOL,1) =  RIGHT(CCOL,1) AND RIGHT(ACOL,1) =  RIGHT(DCOL,1)` [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6978/5)

Comment: I figured it out: `SELECT n1,n2,n3,a AS AValues,b AS BValues, c AS CValues, d AS DValues
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM t1) p
    UNPIVOT (a FOR ACOL IN (a1,a2,a3))AS u1
    UNPIVOT (b FOR BCOL IN (b1,b2,b3))AS u2
    UNPIVOT (c FOR CCOL IN (c1,c2,c3))AS u3
    UNPIVOT (d FOR DCOL IN (d1,d2,d3))AS u4
WHERE RIGHT(ACOL,1) =  RIGHT(BCOL,1) AND RIGHT(BCOL,1) = RIGHT(CCOL,1) AND RIGHT(CCOL,1) = RIGHT(DCOL,1);`

Comment: I'm having problems transferring this to my implementation and am getting duplicate rows/permutations.  I'm not sure I completely understand how the where clause is working and what it is doing.

Comment: Figured it out.  The RIGHT( ,1) function is referencing the last digit/character of the column headings not the field values.

Answer (score 0):

How about a union query:

```
SELECT
    n1
    , n2
    , n3
    , a1 AS [As]
    , b1 AS [Bs]
FROM 
    t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    n1
    , n2
    , n3
    , a2
    , b2
FROM 
    t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    n1
    , n2
    , n3
    , a3
    , b3
FROM t1
order by a1
```